# Why is ALSA only recording in 44100Hz?

Tags: sound, alsa, audio-recording

I'm trying to setup audio recording on Ubuntu 14.04.3 Server. I need to record audio in 16000Hz and I'm using an external USB soundcard, that definitely supports this sample rate.

However, when I try:

```
 arecord -f S16_LE -r 16000 -D default -c 1 test.wav
```

I always receive the following warning:

```
Warning: rate is not accurate (requested = 48000Hz, got = 44100Hz)
```

And this comes always. I tried different audio devices as well but it only ever gives me 44100Hz.

Here is my `/etc/asound.conf`:

```
pcm.custom {
        type hw
        card UA25EX
}

ctl.custom {
        type hw
        card UA25EX
}

pcm.!default pcm.custom
ctl.!default ctl.custom
```

I also tried to set the sample rate in that file explicitly, but that only results in a bad configuration, so that the device is not found any more.

So what can I do, to record in 16000Hz?

**EDIT**

```
> arecord -d 1 -v test.wav
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE


> cat /proc/asound/U0x41e0x30d3/stream0
Playback:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 48000, 44100

Capture:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 2
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 1
    Endpoint: 2 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 48000, 44100
```

Comment: The parameter `-f S16_LE` specifies a recording sample rate of 44100 hz.  You could try changing the order of parameters to see if placing your sample rate before the format parameter changes the result.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks but unfortunately it did not help

Comment: Can you remove the `-f S16_LE` and use the resulting recording?

Comment: @CharlesGreen It still doesn't work if I remove it.

Comment: Hm.  Lets try a simple test - If you execute `arecord -d 1 -v test.wav`, can you append the output of that command to your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen sure and thanks. I just edited my question.

Comment: Show the contents of `/proc/asound/UA25EX/stream0`.

Comment: @CL. ok, I added that as well (I just mixed up the device in my original question). Looks it has indeed only 44100 and 48000Hz. Is that a hardware limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called "Sound Blaster Play!" device supports only 44.1 and 48 kHz.

Comment: Thanks, I was sure, that it must support 16kHz. I still wonder if it is not possible to somehow record in 16kHz since it is just a third of 48kHz. I also tried to find other USB sound cards, that support that, but so far without luck. Do you have any further advice on either hardware or software solutions to achieve recording in 16kHz?

Comment: Why not resample?